# For Flutter Mobile, How to Push a New Route by a Drag/Swipe Gesture While Controlling the Position of the Routes (Like Swipe to Pop in iOS)

Tags: flutter, navigation, swipe, gesture, forward

As most of you already know, Flutter offers a Cupertino navigation transition that represents the native iOS behavior when navigating to previous route. You can start swiping from the left edge of the device and a navigation animation is started. Unless the user ends touching to the screen, the user is in control of the position of the current (above) and the previous (below) routes.

According to the release position and velocity, whether the screen will be popped or not and the animation controller takes the rest of the job.

I want to implement exactly opposite of this. When the user starts swiping from the right edge of the screen to the left, the gesture will be detected. The new route will be created and be positioned on the right. User can drag the new route to the left (into the scene). After the release of the touch, it will be decided to whether center the new route (complete) or let it go away (cancel).

This behavior can be observed inside Safari browser, for example. You can navigate backwards by start swiping from the left edge. Moreover, you can navigate forward by starting to swipe from the right end of the screen.

Also, it is possible to experience a similar UI/UX behavior in TikTok app. When watching a video on the “For You” screen (that’s the default home page of the TikTok), the user can start dragging the screen from right to left and when the gesture detected, the profile screen of the current content’s owner will be shown. As mentioned above, the user will be in control of the position by dragging. When the user ends touching it will complete or cancel the navigation based on the situation.

**Question is:**
I am a power user of Flutter since the very early beta days of it. I made quite complex UX implementations till today. However, this type of a navigation need haven’t been an issue and didn’t come to my mind.

I did a deep research on the Flutter source code, internet, Flutter issues, pub.dev, etc. Yet, I couldn’t find a logically easy solution.

Does anybody know how to do that? Indeed we can use the CupertinoPageRoute and extend upon it but my mind just stopped at the moment.

Side note: The end result could be like a parallax effect or like a PageView.

Comment: don't know if you found a solution but I was facing the same uses cases in my app with multiple drag axis and I finally workarounded by showing/removing a new widget page in a ```Stack``` according the visibility condition on swipe. But no push

Comment: In my case, there was a WillPopScope somewhere in my widget tree which was preventing the Swipe Gesture in iOS. By using TargetPlatform.iOS i was able to conditionally show the WillPopScope Widget on only Android.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to implement this?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't @LucasAschenbach